# Hiding Asp.NET MVC version in the header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-10

I am familiar with hiding the ASP.Net MVC version that shows up in the header, when used network tools to inspect, by adding `MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;` in the global.asax.cs file's Application_Start() method.

But my situation is, I do not have access to the repository / code and I have access only to the web server / IIS and the application's web.config

Is there a way to implement this , to hide the MVC version, in any of the out-bound rules ?

I am working with limited tools, since I do not have access to the code, and all I have on the web server is the packaged bundle of the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you don't have access to the code, this question might be better suited for e.g. [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) since the only tool you have available is the web server. On that note, I'd recommend looking at the question [How to Remove IIS/ASP.NET Response Headers](https://serverfault.com/questions/24885/how-to-remove-iis-asp-net-response-headers) on Server Fault.

Comment: #Jeremy Caney, I have already visited that page and there's no solution like the one below provided by #Hury Shen, on the IIS level itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this requirement by url rewrite rule. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** Install the [URL Rewrite extension](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

**2.** Then you can find the URL Rewrite module in your application site in IIS manager like below screenshot.

[image]

**3.** Double click URL Rewrite module and click "View Server Variables.."

[image]

**4.** Add a server variable named `RESPONSE_X-AspNetMvc-Version`

[image]

**5.** Then back to rules and add a outbound rule.

[image]

**6.** Set the outbound rule as below:

[image]

**7.** After apply the rule and browse your site, you can find the value of `X-AspNetMvc-Version` in response header is hidden.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Hury shen, will try your steps today.

Comment: awesome @Hury Shen, thanks for the detailed steps and it worked. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to hide the title 'X-AspNetMvc-Version' as well in the response header?

Comment: @Ron I'm not sure, I'm afraid we can't implement it.